# How can a spring WebClient response be piped, zipped and forwarded to another request?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I am trying to download several files from remote locations, adding them to a zip file and then sending the resulting zip file to another location. The files in the zip can be quite big, big enough to cause all kinds of buffer issues, so it really should be a streaming solution.

What I have made so far works if I download the files in another thread, writing it to a PipedOutputStream which is connected to a PipedInputStream.

See this example:

```java
void test() throws IOException {
    var outputLocation = "http://localhost:5000/anything";
    var pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    var pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream);

    var thread = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            var zip = new ZipOutputStream(pipedOutputStream);

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                // This should really be a web request for a remote file, which should
                // return an InputStream that can be piped into the zip output stream
                zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test" + i + ".txt"));
                new ByteArrayInputStream(("Hello " + i).getBytes())
                    .transferTo(zip);
                zip.closeEntry();
            }

            zip.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    thread.start();

    var response = webClient.post()
        .uri(outputLocation)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new InputStreamResource(pipedInputStream)))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
        .block();

    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
}
```

What I am really wondering about is how to get this done in a more reactor appropriate way?

Another attempt I did was to first create the upload request, and subscribing to it, but the program finishes before it can say it is complete.

See

```java
void test2() throws IOException {
    var outputLocation = "http://localhost:5000/anything";
    var pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    var pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInputStream);

    var response = webClient.post()
        .uri(outputLocation)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(new InputStreamResource(pipedInputStream)))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
        .subscribe((a) -> {
            System.out.println("Completed");
        });

    try {
        var zip = new ZipOutputStream(pipedOutputStream);

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // This should really be a web request for a remote file, which should
            // return an InputStream that can be piped into the zip output stream
            zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("test" + i + ".txt"));
            // should be: downloadFile().transferTo(zip);
            new ByteArrayInputStream(("Hello " + i).getBytes())
                .transferTo(zip);
            zip.closeEntry();
        }

        zip.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // This method returns before the "Completed" part is outputted, due to how 
    // this whole system works. How do I "block" until the upload request is done?
}
```

My suspicion is that I should be creating some kind of Flux and passing that to the request as a body producer, but how would that even work?